Microsoft MAUI MediaElement FindResouce is not able to identify the Resouce file
I have tried all the below combination but still the resource is not loading for the MediaElement.FromResource() method.
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromUri("http://thinkingform.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/video-sample-mp4.mp4?_=1"); //this is working 
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromUri("https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-12s.mp3"); //this is working                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("embed://onStart.mp3"); //made the music file as a embedded resource then also it did not worked.                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("Resource://Raw/onStart.mp3");                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("resource://onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("resource://Resources/Raw/onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("resource://Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3");                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("embed://Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromFile("E:\\Trainings\\MAUI\\Flora\\Flora\\Resources\\Raw\\onStart.mp3"); //this is working                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("//Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3");  //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("\\Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("resource:\\Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                     
//onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); // After setting the file to embeded resource also not loaded the music file                     
onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("embed://Flora.Resources.Raw.onStart.mp3"); //not loaded the music file                    
onStartMusic.ShouldAutoPlay = true; 
onStartMusic.Play();


please format your question properly

You can refer to embedded resources.

As mentioned in documentation here. The shorthand URI scheme's like embed:// only works when Source is set from XAML
Assuming that your audio file is in Resources/Raw/onStart.mp3
Then make sure that the build action is set to MauiAsset for the audio file.
Rebuild the project.
Then below assigning should work. Same is mentioned in documentation.
onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("onStart.mp3");


In order to create the above code i have followed the below Microsoft Documantation of the MediaElement in MAUI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=windows
According to this document
But still the media file is not recognized ?
We are able to play the remote Uri using FromUri method and the local file with exact location using FromFile method but only FromResource is not working and it is not throwing any exception so this is very confusing i have tried all different combinations but still no result !!!

@jason i have formatted the code please have a look

@liyu i have followed the specified document please find the below detailed document as follows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=windows

@liyu as per the mentioned document i have set the resource build properties to MAUIAsset and utilized the following method.
onStartMusic.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("onStart.mp3");
But still it is not loading the file.

where are you setting the source please try to set it in constructor of the page where media element is present.

i have followed the documentation of the Microsoft but still not loading the resource file there is no exception as well. It is confusing

@SunilG.V.  Bhavanesh N is right . Do as what he said. My codes worked fine.

@Bhavanesh N yes i am setting the source in the constructor only but still no result.

does the audio play when played normally??... make the audio name in only lower case letters ?? clean sln, delete obj,bin files and rebuild you solution... dont forget set build action of the file to maui asset
